# Como obter todos os paths de uma JTree?

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Como posso obter todos os *paths* de uma `JTree` incluindo os *nodes* que têm parents que não seja o root?

```
root
  exemplo1
    exemplo1.1
  exemplo2
    exemplo2.1
```

Se eu fizer algo do gênero:

```
for(int i = 0; i< tree.getRowCount(); i++){
   TreePath path = tree.getPathForRow(i);
   System.out.println(path);
}
```

O *output* será:

```
[root]
[root,exemplo1]
[root,exemplo2]
```

Como posso ter acesso ao *path* ou ao *index* do `exemplo1.1` e `exemplo2.1` ?

Comment: @renan Por que a "recompensa" em uma questão que você mesmo respondeu? Ainda há duvidas? Espero que consiga a sua resposta :)

Comment: @renan Mas você lançou a recompensa as 17:15 (UTC) e o Mateus respondeu as 16:24 (UTC). Estou confuso.

Comment: @renan Apesar de aparecer sempre algo como "1 nova resposta" ou "2 novas respostas" sem refresh, parece plausível, ok, que bom que encontrou a solução, até mais. +1 na sua resposta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somente complementando a resposta do @renan, você também pode varrer o `JTree` dessa maneira:

```
private void outroMetodo() {
    List<Object[]> niveis = new ArrayList<>();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode raiz = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) theTree.getModel().getRoot();

    int index = 0;
    int posicao = 0;

    niveis.add(new Object[] { raiz, "", (int) 0 });
    index++;

    while (niveis.size() != 0) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode no;
        do {
            Object[] nivel = niveis.get(posicao);
            no = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) nivel[0];

            System.out.printf("%s (%d)\n", nivel[1] + "--" + no.toString(), nivel[2]);

            Enumeration subNiveis = no.children();

            while (subNiveis.hasMoreElements()) {
                niveis.add(index++, new Object[] { subNiveis.nextElement(), nivel[1] + "--",  
                        (int) nivel[2] + 1});
            }

            niveis.remove(nivel);
            if (no.getChildCount() != 0) {
                index -= no.getChildCount();
            } else {
                index = 1;
            }
        } while (no != null && no.getChildCount() != 0);
    }
}
```

Basicamente utilizei um `ArrayList` para controlar os nós, a cada iteração eu verifiquei se o nó corrente possuía filhos, caso possuísse, os nós filhos eram adicionados abaixo do nó corrente e depois o nó corrente era removido do `ArrayList` e assim continuava a iteração até não existirem mais nós.

Na lista de *array* de objetos (`List<Object[]> niveis = new ArrayList<>();`), os seguintes itens são utilizados:

- niveis[ 0 ] - nó a ser verificado.
- niveis[ 1 ] - texto para organização dos níveis.
- niveis[ 2 ] - nível dentro de cada nó.

O resultado pode ser visto na imagem abaixo.

[image: resultado do código]

Answer (score 5):

> Como posso obter todos os paths de uma JTree incluindo os nodes que
>   têm parents que não seja o root?

Fiz uma pesquisa e a lógica para ter acesso a todos os *nodes* é bem simples.

Primeiro, obtenha o *root* da sua `JTree` utilizando o método `getRoot`:

```
TreeModel theRoot = (TreeModel) tree.getModel().getRoot();
```

Em seguida, basta contar quantos elementos filhos esse *root* possui, para isto existe o método `getChildCount`:

```
int childCount = tree.getModel().getChildCount(theRoot);
```

Tendo a quantidade de elementos filhos e o *root*, basta criar um loop de 0 até a quantidade de elementos filhos, com isso você pode acessar cada índice por meio do método `getChild`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
   System.out.println( tree.getModel().getChild(theRoot, i) ); // faz algo...
```

Para acessar os *nodes* dentro dos elementos filhos, basta fazer o mesmo processo:
- Contar quantos elementos há internamente
- Iniciar um loop de 0 até a quantidade de elementos.

---

> Como posso ter acesso ao path ou ao index do exemplo1.1 e exemplo2.1 ?

```
// Acessando o filho 'Exemplo1 -> 1'
String primeiro = tree.getModel().getChild(Exemplo1, 0).toString(); // O primeiro indice inicia-se em '0'

//Acessando o filho 'Exemplo2 -> 2'
String segundo = tree.getModel().getChild(Exemplo2, 0).toString();
```

Montei um código simples de teste contendo a mesma estrutura de `JTree` criada por você na pergunta, segue a imagem:

[image: jtree is nice]

O exemplo é simples: Ele vai acessa os dois elementos filhos (Exemplo1 > 1 **e** Exemplo2 > 2) e armazenar o nome em uma `String`. A saída é:

```
1
2
```

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    public MyWindow() {
        super("StackOverflow");
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        // Propriedades do JFrame
        setSize(500, 500);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode theRoot = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Root");

        DefaultMutableTreeNode theFirstExample = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Exemplo1");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode firstExampleChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("1");
        theFirstExample.add(firstExampleChild);

        DefaultMutableTreeNode theSecondExample = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Exemplo2");
        DefaultMutableTreeNode secondExampleChild = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("2");
        theSecondExample.add(secondExampleChild);

        theRoot.add(theFirstExample);
        theRoot.add(theSecondExample);

        JTree theTree = new JTree(theRoot);
        getContentPane().add(theTree);

        // Acessando o filho 'Exemplo1 -> 1'
        String exampleOne = theTree.getModel().getChild(theFirstExample, 0).toString();

        //Acessando o filho 'Exemplo2 -> 2'
        String exampleTwo = theTree.getModel().getChild(theSecondExample, 0).toString();

        System.out.println(exampleOne);
        System.out.println(exampleTwo);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyWindow().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```